Making a superposition proportional to a 1-cosine envelope
Here is a simple circuit that produces a superposition proportional to a sine envelope $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin(\pi k/n)$:

Is there also a simple circuit to prepare a 1-cosine envelope? A state proportional to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1 - \cos(2\pi k/n)$.
Note this is a different state. In particular, the 1-cosine envelope lacks the slope discontinuity that the sine envelope has:


My first idea was to find coefficients $c_i$ so that $\sin(c_i \pi)$ gives the desired envelope. In the case of $1-\cos$, we need coefficients satisfying $\sin(c_i \pi) = (1 - \cos(2i\pi/N))/2$. At this point, I suppose there are a few ways to map $|i\rangle \mapsto e^{-i c_i\pi}$, but I don't know of any that are particularly simple.
